# Can anyone explain this part of the Virial Theorem to me?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, virial-theorem

I have three questions:

> •) When is the *Virial Theorem* used?
>
> •) Why is $n=-1$ in $V(r) = r^n$?
>
> •) Also why is the average Kinetic Energy equal to half of the average negative Potential Energy?

I'm especially confused on the $n=-1$ part. Is it because when a system interacts with only gravity, we have to apply the equation: $F=GMm/r^2$? But then should $r=2$ (or $-2$ because you can write it as $F=GMmr^{-2}$)?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555248/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic i didn't get much help from that post. That is why I wrote this new one

Comment: wikipedia is pretty good on this, but from your question I guess you need a more introductory level discussion. The $V(r)$ refers to potential energy. Force is the gradient of this. Therefore the case $n = -1$ occurs in Newtonian gravity and in electrostatics (Coulomb's law).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to physics and I came upon this topic on a test. I still don't understand WHY  n=−1. Can you please re explain? Are there any videos I can watch or websites I can read? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done some calculus? If you've learned about integrals you should be able to follow this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Potential_energy_for_gravitational_forces_between_two_bodies OTOH, it might be a bit daunting if you haven't learned how to do calculus with vectors yet. Annoyingly, that page has a lot of vector stuff, it would be nice if they showed the simple 1D non-vector version first.

Answer (score 3):

The potential is defined as the work required to move a unit test charge/mass/whatever from infinity to $r$:

$$ V(r) = \int_{\infty}^r F(r')dr' $$

so if:

$$ F(r) = cr^{n-1} $$

then:

$$ V(r) = c\int_{\infty}^r r^{n-1}dr'=\frac c n r'^n\big |^r_{\infty} = \frac c n r^n $$

(Note, for $n < 0$ you start from infinity. For $n>0$, you would start at $r=0$).

Hence a $1/r^2$ force has a $-1/r$ potential.

Now the viral theorem is about averages for any orbit, but one can get an idea for it by looking at circular orbit. Balancing the centripetal force with the central force:

$$m (\frac{v^2} r) = c r^{n-1} $$

and subbing kinetic energy $T=\frac 1 2 mv^2 $:

$$ 2T = cr^n = nV(r) $$

so the relationship between kinetic energy and potential energy is:

$$ T = \frac n 2 V $$

For gravity, this means the average kinetic energy is half the (negative) potential energy.